# Overriding Operator Precedence

Tags: perl

I am confused with operator precedence in Perl. I have expression like:

```
$a || $b ? join ",", @$b : ""
```

I thought Perl would create a list context:

```
my $result = $a || ($b ? join ",", @$b : ""); 
# I thought (...) would create a list context and make result = 1,
# but $result is correctly set to the join of @$b
# Why does it not create list context?
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Is this related to your earlier question about using either `@ARGV` or `STDIN`? A more concrete example would be nice. In general, I would only use the conditional operator for very simple cases, since it is a little harder to mentally parse than a simple `if`/`else`.

Comment: @thissuitisblacknot well they are not quite related but they are the problems I had in one project. if else is always a universal solution of course but I just wanna know some dirty hacks of perl

Answer (score 2):

From the section on context in [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context):

> Assignment is a little bit special in that it uses its left argument to determine the context for the right argument. *Assignment to a scalar evaluates the right-hand side in scalar context*, while assignment to an array or hash evaluates the righthand side in list context. Assignment to a list (or slice, which is just a list anyway) also evaluates the right-hand side in list context.

(emphasis added)

And from [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

> **Conditional Operator**
>
> [...]
>
> Scalar or list context propagates downward into the 2nd or 3rd argument, whichever is selected.
>
> ```
> $a = $ok ? $b : $c;  # get a scalar
> @a = $ok ? @b : @c;  # get an array
> $a = $ok ? @b : @c;  # oops, that's just a count!
> ```

As for precedence, `||` has a higher precedence than the conditional operator, so

```
my $result = $foo || $bar ? 0 : 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
my $result = ($foo || $bar) ? 0 : 1;
```

Note that the parentheses do not create list context, which is a common misconception. They aren't necessary in this case, but they do improve readability, so I would recommend using them.

Again, in

```
my $result = $foo || ($bar ? 0 : 1);
```

parentheses do not create list context. With [`||`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Or)

> Scalar or list context propagates down to the right operand if it is evaluated.

so `($bar ? 0 : 1)` is evaluated in scalar context (assuming `$foo` is a true value; if not, `||` short-circuits and the RHS isn't evaluated at all).

Comment: Parentheses do not create list context? What do they do?

Comment: @texasbruce In this case, the parentheses are simply used for grouping; they simply affect precedence. Also, don't confuse list *values* with list *context*. See [List value constructors](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) in `perldoc perldata`.

Comment: @texasbruce Also see [ikegami's answer to "Can the empty list be in scalar context?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6970812/176646) and the [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) tutorial on PerlMonks. It's a common misconception that parentheses create a list; they don't. The posts I linked explain two frequent sources of confusion: `my $foo = ();` (the `()` is not actually a list, although it is sometimes called the null list or empty list); and `my ($foo) = ...`